# How to fix "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage'\r"

Tags: python, azure, apache, flask, azure-blob-storage

I'm getting this error when trying to run project on azure windows server but It's working fine on Ubuntu machine and My Local Windows machine. I have deploy flask project on Apache with mod_wsgi server.
I have already installed the all the required dependencies.

[image: Packages]

```
[Thu Feb 18 09:03:58.636970 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5724:tid 1120] [client 110.225.67.165:26675] mod_wsgi (pid=5724): Failed to exec Python script file 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/flask/app/src/app.wsgi'.
[Thu Feb 18 09:03:58.636970 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5724:tid 1120] [client 110.225.67.165:26675] mod_wsgi (pid=5724): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/flask/app/src/app.wsgi'.
[Thu Feb 18 09:03:58.636970 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5724:tid 1120] [client 110.225.67.165:26675] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Thu Feb 18 09:03:58.636970 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5724:tid 1120] [client 110.225.67.165:26675]   File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/flask/app/src/app.wsgi", line 4, in <module>\r
[Thu Feb 18 09:03:58.636970 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5724:tid 1120] [client 110.225.67.165:26675]     from wsgi import app as application\r
[Thu Feb 18 09:03:58.636970 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5724:tid 1120] [client 110.225.67.165:26675]   File "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\flask\\app\\src\\wsgi.py", line 6, in <module>\r
[Thu Feb 18 09:03:58.636970 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5724:tid 1120] [client 110.225.67.165:26675]     from server import app\r
[Thu Feb 18 09:03:58.636970 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5724:tid 1120] [client 110.225.67.165:26675]   File "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\flask\\app\\src\\server.py", line 10, in <module>\r
[Thu Feb 18 09:03:58.636970 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5724:tid 1120] [client 110.225.67.165:26675]     from azure_portal.blob_storage import BlobStorage\r
[Thu Feb 18 09:03:58.636970 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5724:tid 1120] [client 110.225.67.165:26675]   File "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\flask\\app\\src\\azure_portal\\blob_storage.py", line 5, in <module>\r
[Thu Feb 18 09:03:58.636970 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5724:tid 1120] [client 110.225.67.165:26675]     from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient\r
[Thu Feb 18 09:03:58.636970 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5724:tid 1120] [client 110.225.67.165:26675] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage'\r
```

Please help me to resolve the issue. It would be very helpful for me.

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `azure.storage` is installed on the machine?

Please [install it before you run your project](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage/):

```
script: pip install azure-storage
```

*Try `pip list` to see what all modules are installed on your machine.*

*Also, see that, the version which is used by your code, is installed on your machine.*